# Create template to show product by attributes

Tags: wordpress, templates, attributes, woocommerce, product

In WooCommerce I have created one attribute called "country" with two terms. I add this attribute to my products with this terms.

I obtain my terms this way:

```
echo '<ul>';
$terms = get_terms( 'pa_country', 'hide_empty=0' );
foreach ($terms as $term) :
    $term_link = get_term_link( $term->slug, 'pa_country' );
    echo '<li><a href="'.$term_link.'" title="'.$term->name.'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>';
endforeach;
echo '</ul>';
```

But when I click on the link it don't use my template (but only reload home page). My link is like this:

```
/?taxonomy=pa_country&term=usa
```

So inside the woocommerce templates folder of my theme, I have created 2 templates:

- taxonomy-country.php
- taxonomy-pa_country.php

But they don't work!

Any idea?

Thanks in advances.

Comment: Solved !!!  In admin, edit the attribute and make sure its set to be 'public'. There is a checkbox. And I don't have to create any template, because use archive-product.php